# Python with Simple Salesforce dynamic SOQL query issue: ERROR at Row:1:Column:98\nline 1:98 no viable alternative at character '\\'",

Tags: python, simple-salesforce

I have to retrieved data from a SOSL query using simple saleforce with no issues. This query will search for duplicate leads or contacts in Salesforce and then
get the multiple records retrieved and then  Run a SOQL query using these records  to get the earliest record based on created date. I should get a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT LeadId,CreatedDate FROM CampaignMember WHERE LeadId IN ('00Q2g000001d0Pc','00Q2g000001cye4')  AND Campaign.Name Like '%LeadGen%' And Campaign.Status <> 'Aborted' and Campaign.Status <> 'Completed' ORDER BY CreatedDate limit 1
```

However, when I call up the SOQL statement I am getting this error:
***Response content: [{'message': "\nLIKE '%LeadGen%' AND LeadId IN (\'00Q2g000001cye4EAA\',\'00Q2g000001d0PcEAI\')\nERROR at Row:1:Column:98\nline 1:98 no viable alternative at character '\'", 'errorCode': 'MALFORMED_QUERY'***

## ***Here is the code including both working SOSL and erroneous SOQL statement***

```
if 'FirstName' in info and 'LastName' in info and 'Company' in info and 'State' in info and 'City' in info and info['FirstName'] != None and info['FirstName'] != '' and info['LastName'] != None and info['LastName'] != '' and info['Company'] != None and info['Company'] != '' and info['State'] != None and info['State'] != '' and info['City'] != None and info['City'] != '':
            self.company = info['Company']
            self.company = self.company.replace('-', '\-')
            self.company = self.company.replace('&', '\&')
            self.paramBRM =  info['FirstName']+ " AND " +info['LastName']+" AND "+ self.company +" AND " + info['City'] +" AND "+info['State']
            print(self.paramBRM)
            self.query = self.__sf.search("""
                FIND {%s}
                IN ALL FIELDS
            RETURNING
            Contact (Id),Lead(Id)
            """ % self.paramBRM)
            print(self.query)
            self.result = self.query['searchRecords'] 
            if len(self.result) == 1:
                self.Id = self.result[0]['Id']
                print(self.Id)
                valid = self.result[0]['Id']
                print(valid)
                if valid.startswith('003'):
                    contacts = "'"+self.result[0]['Id']+"'"
                    print(contacts)
                    self.Id = self.result[0]['Id']
                    self.Type = self.result[0]['attributes']['type']
                    return(self.Type, self.Id)
                else:
                    leads = "'"+self.result[0]['Id']+"'"
                    print(leads)
                    self.Id = self.result[0]['Id']
                    self.Type = self.result[0]['attributes']['type']
                    return(self.Type, self.Id)
            else:
                lindx = 0
                cindx = 0
                lstcontacts = []
                lstleads = []
                lstleads = []
                idx = 0
                prospect_name = 'LeadGen'
                for someId in self.result[idx]:
                    print(idx)
                    if someId.startswith('003'):
                        print('<<  OK GOT CONTACTS >>')
                        lstcontacts.append("'"+self.result[idx]['Id']+"',")
                        print('<< A contact value >>')
                        print(lstcontacts)
                        cindx += 1
                    else:
                        print('<<  OK GOT LEADS >>')
                        print(self.result[idx]['Id'])
                        lstleads.append("'"+self.result[idx]['Id']+"',")
                        print('<< A lead value:>>')
                        print(lstleads)
                        lindx += 1
                    idx += 1
                    print('<<<<  Counter >>>>')
                    print(idx)
                print(lindx)
                print(cindx)
                 #Parse Leads list to get SOQL query list of leads
                if len(lstleads) > 0:
                    lindx -= 1
                    print('<< Lead Index for popping >> ')
                    print(lindx)
                    temp_last_lead = lstleads.pop(lindx)
                    print('<< LAST LEAD >>')
                    print(temp_last_lead)
                    print('<<< LOADING lead string >>>')
                    for ldvalue in lstleads:
                        leads += ldvalue
                    leads += temp_last_lead.replace(",", "")
                    print(leads)
                    print(prospect_name)
                    print('<<  Go To LEADS  QUERY>>')
```

## The next line is where it fails:

```
                    self.queryL = self.__sf.query_all("SELECT LeadId,CreatedDate FROM CampaignMember WHERE Campaign.Name LIKE '%"+ self.adding_escape_char(prospect_name) + "%' AND LeadId IN ("+self.adding_escape_char(leads)+") And Campaign.Status <>'" + self.adding_escape_char('Aborted') + "' And Campaign.Status <>'" +self.adding_escape_char('Completed') +"' ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC limit 1")
                    self.result = self.queryL['records']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've escaped quotes in your query string in a way that you do not need to. Stripping out the wrapping quotes and function call, you have

```
SELECT LeadId,CreatedDate 
FROM CampaignMember 
WHERE Campaign.Name LIKE '%"+ self.adding_escape_char(prospect_name) + "%' 
AND LeadId IN ("+self.adding_escape_char(leads)+") 
And Campaign.Status <>'" + self.adding_escape_char('Aborted') + "' 
And Campaign.Status <>'" +self.adding_escape_char('Completed') +"' ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC limit 1")
```

and what the error is telling you is that you have a spurious escaped single quote in your `LeadId` filter:

> Response content: [{'message': "\nLIKE '%LeadGen%' AND LeadId IN (\'00Q2g000001cye4EAA\',\'00Q2g000001d0PcEAI\')\nERROR at Row:1:Column:98\nline 1:98 no viable alternative at character '\'", 'errorCode': 'MALFORMED_QUERY'

That single quote at the first LeadId shouldn't be there. You want a literal single quote. Since `leads` is a list of quoted Lead Ids, you should not call `self.adding_escape_char(leads)` for this parameter. You also don't need to call it for static strings like `'Aborted'` because you can see there is no possibility of an injection attack there.

Your code could be significantly streamlined by using modern Python tools and best practices. For example, this problem query could be cleaned up using fstrings to let you better inspect its structure:

```
lead_ids = self.adding_escape_char(leads)
prospect_name = self.adding_escape_char(prospect_name)
self.queryL = self.__sf.query_all(
        f"""SELECT LeadId, CreatedDate 
            FROM CampaignMember 
            WHERE Campaign.Name LIKE '%{prospect_name}%'
                  AND LeadId IN ({lead_ids}) 
                  AND Campaign.Status <> 'Aborted'                      
                  AND Campaign.Status <> 'Completed'             
            ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC 
            LIMIT 1"""
)
self.result = self.queryL['records']
```

Elsewhere, you can reduce this whole method to just a few lines of code by using list comprehensions and the `join()` method. For example, you can turn a list of Ids into a query string just by doing

```
", ".join(f"'{id}'" for id in id_list)
```

Comment: Thanks David, this really helped. I got the query to work now. And I like the touch were you don't need to call self.adding_escape_char() on leads. I am new to both python and using simple salesforce so I may not have all the core fundamentals down yet. I appreciate your help.